# Co-propagating fermions with tunneling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bosonization, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

When we have coupled fermions with an opposite chirality, the existence of the tunneling term will effectively act as a mass term and opens up the gap. When we bosonize the theory this mass term corresponds to a cosine term. In the same way if we couple two co-propagating fermions, we can show tunneling can't cause any gap opening. My question is how can we see that in the bosonization picture?